# Can't Access Contents of Geocoder Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using the search function in geocoder, specifically the one for an IP address:

```
Geocoder.search("204.57.220.1")
```

When I type the command into the console and store the results as a variable I can view the contents:

```
[#<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x0000000241d848 @data={"ip"=>"204.57.220.1", 
"country_code"=>"US", "country_name"=>"United States", "region_code"=>"WA",
"region_name"=>"Washington", "city"=>"Redmond", "zip_code"=>"98052", 
"time_zone"=>"America/Los_Angeles", "latitude"=>47.674, "longitude"=>-122.122, 
"metro_code"=>819}, @cache_hit=nil>]
```

but I can't figure out how to access the results. I've tried:

results.@data.zip_code, results[@data.zip_code], results[@data.results] and pretty much every other combonation I could think of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this returns an array. This means that you need to do something like:

```
results = Geocoder.search("204.57.220.1")
first_result = results.first
p first_result.data
p first_result.data['ip']
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Geocoder.search("204.57.220.1")` is returning an array, you have to grab the first element of the array first, and then grab the `data`.

Do it this way:

```
results = Geocoder.search("204.57.220.1")
data = results.first.data
```

This will give you the `data` hash and from there you can extract your required data:

```
puts data['zip_code']
puts data['ip']
. . . 
. . .
```